# Select Query containing tuple With mixed single as well as double quotes

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

Postgresql select query containing tuple with single quotes as well as double quotes when giving this tuple as the input to select query it genrates error stating that specific value is not present in the database.

I have treid converting that list of values to JSON list with double quotes but that doesn't help either.

```
list = ['mango', 'apple', "chikoo's", 'banana', "jackfruit's"]

query = """select category from  "unique_shelf" where  "Unique_Shelf_Names"  in {}""" .format(list)
```

ERROR: column "chikoo's" doesn't exist

Infact chikoo's does exist
But due to double quotes its not fetching the value.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please don't use **list** as a variable name, list is a reserved keyword and you don't wanna overwrite it.

Secondly, using "" around tables and columns is bad practice, use ` instead.

Thirdly, when you format an array, it outputs as

```sql
select category from `unique_shelf` 
where `Unique_Shelf_Names` in (['mango', 'apple', "chikoo's", 'banana', "jackfruit's"])
```

Which is not a valid SQL syntax.

You can join all values with a comma

```py
>>>print("""select category from `unique_shelf` where `Unique_Shelf_Names` in {})""".format(','.join(l)))
select category from `unique_shelf` 
where `Unique_Shelf_Names` in (mango,apple,chikoo's,banana,jackfruit's)
```

The issue here is that the values inside the in bracket are not quoted. We can do that by formatting them beforehand using double quotes(")

```py
l = ['mango', 'apple', "chikoo's", 'banana', "jackfruit's"]
list_with_quotes = ['"{}"'.format(x) for x in l]

query = """
select category from `unique_shelf` 
where `Unique_Shelf_Names` in ({})""" .format(','.join(list_with_quotes))
```

This will give you an output of

```sql
select category from `unique_shelf` 
where `Unique_Shelf_Names` in ("mango","apple","chikoo's","banana","jackfruit's")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but output of ```list_with_quotes = ['"mango"','"apple"','"chikoo\'s"','"banana"','"jackfruit\'s"']``` They are not double quotes they aredouble quotes with single quotes so whwn i give this input to select query it searches for value with double quotes in database like "chikoo's" but the value present is chikoo's s.

Comment: I am trying to fetch those fruits values from database through `select query` then using `fetchall()` function putting those value in list and after that putting those list values to another select query and that is where its giving me the error